# Laravel Model data not available in Controller

Tags: php, laravel

I'm new to Laravel. I might be making a basic mistake here but I've been trying and researching for a while, need some guidance here.

I have 2 routes:

```
Route::get('ordercontents/{ordercontent}', 'App\Http\Controllers\OrderContentsController@edit');

Route::get('ordercontents/delete/{ordercontents}', 'App\Http\Controllers\OrderContentsController@destroy');
```

Inside `OrderContentsController.php` I have the 2 functions, one to edit a record and another to delete it.

```
public function edit(\App\Models\Order_content $ordercontents)
    {
        dd($ordercontents); //the attributes will come out empty
        $orderContentId = $ordercontents->id;
        $ocs = getOrderContentDetails($orderContentId);
        return view('ordercontents.edit')->with('ordercontents', $ocs);
    }

public function destroy(\App\Models\Order_content $ordercontents)
    {
        $orderId = $ordercontents->order_id;
        $ordercontents->delete();
        return redirect('/new-ordercontent/' . $orderId)->with('success', 'Material removido da ordem de serviço!');
    }
```

The model exists and is called `Order_content`.
Everything works well for the `destroy` function.
However, I'm struggling with the `edit` function.
If I do a `dd($ordercontents);` the `attributes` array of the object comes empty inside the `edit` function.
What am I missing? Thanks!

Comment: because the name of the type-hinted parameter in your method signature does not match the name of the route parameter, so there is no Route Model Binding happening, it is just Dependency Injection (a new non existing Model instance)

Comment: Ah, so true, thanks a lot. I looked at it many times and didn't notice that. Really appreciate it. If you want to add that as the answer, I'll gladly accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to make sure the name of the variable that is type-hinted in your method signature matches the route parameter for Route Model Binding:

> "Laravel automatically resolves Eloquent models defined in routes or controller actions whose type-hinted variable names match a route segment name." - [Laravel Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#implicit-binding)

The method signature for edit can be adjusted to match the route parameter name:

```
public function edit(\App\Models\Order_content $ordercontent)
```

When these do not match you will have Dependency Injection happening so a new non-existing Model instance would be injected.

[Laravel 8.x Docs - Routing- Route Model Binding - Implicit Binding](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#implicit-binding)